# Convert Picturebox Image to Transparent VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I'm having a problem when it comes to images with white background. How can I remove the white background or make the image transparent?

For now I'm using this code

```
Dim _ms3 As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
pbSignCapture.Image.Save(_ms3, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
Dim _arrImage3() As Byte = _ms3.GetBuffer()
_ms3.Close()
```

Also saving the image using the `_arrImage3`.

I want to convert the image in the PictureBox to turn the White Background into transparent.

Comment: Please remove mysql tag...

Comment: @theBugger Sorry my mistake didn't put the mysql code but i edited it now.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the `Bitmap` class to open your image files.

```
Dim myImage as new Bitmap("C:\Image file.bmp")
```

And then you can use the [MakeTransparent()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zzst10b(v=vs.110).aspx) or [MakeTransparent(Color)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8517ckds(v=vs.110).aspx) methods:

Get the color of a background pixel.

```
Dim backColor As Color = myImage.GetPixel(1, 1)
```

Make backColor transparent for myBitmap.

```
myImage.MakeTransparent(backColor)
```

**EDIT:**

As I understand from the new details you want to have a `PictureBox` to be transparent where the source image is transparent. Unfortunately this is not possible using `WinForms` because the transparency system is not cascading. You can set the `BackgroundColor`property of pictureBox to transparent, but this is going to act differently from what you may think. The free pixels of the PictureBox control will show the content of the **parent control**.

It means that if you have, for example, a label below your picurebox and set transparent background to the image; the label won't be shown because it is not theparent control of the picturebox.

A workaround is to manually draw the image in the `paint` event of the destination control.

Let's assume that you have a form with many controls and you want to draw ad image over a button (named btn). You'll have to override the form's paint event this way:

```
Private Sub form_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles form.Paint
    Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics    
    g.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("C:/yourimage.png", btn.Location.X, btn.Location.Y)
End Sub
```

Comment: does `myBitmap` is the `PictureBox`?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo

Comment: tried but not working cuz im printing on card also saving it as png in database

Comment: You should edit the question and clearify what do you want to achieve

Comment: im so sorry im not really in good in english but im trying. see my edited post my mistake sir

Comment: +1 for the clear comments in the edit about transparent PictureBox image pixels revealing the parent control color. I fought with this for too long. Decided ImageMagick was the best workaround for final output, but used picturebox and a panel for a resizing/masking/cropping measuring.